# Not able to import paddleocr library on Google Colab

Tags: python, ocr, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I am not able to import paddleocr library on Google Colab after the install of paddlepaddle and paddleocr successfully. It hits the error as shown below:

```
**from paddleocr import PaddleOCR, draw_ocr**



Error: Can not import paddle core while this file exists: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/paddle/fluid/libpaddle.so
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e16532d3d475> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from paddleocr import PaddleOCR, draw_ocr
      2 import os
      3 import cv2
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/paddle/fluid/core.py in <module>
    267 
    268 try:
--> 269     from . import libpaddle
    270 
    271     if avx_supported() and not libpaddle.is_compiled_with_avx():

ImportError: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Previously, everything was okay but I am not able to import paddleOCR today. Appreciate the community help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following steps, I was able to get PaddleOCR to run in Google Colab:

1. Go the the "Runtime" tab, select "Change runtime type" and under "Hardware accelerator" select "GPU".
2. Upload the image to be analyzed in the `content` section of Google Colab.
3. Download the PaddleOCR modules using `pip`:

```
!pip install paddlepaddle-gpu
!pip install paddleocr
```

4. Download `libssl1.1` using Bash:

```
!wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
!sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

5. Clone the PaddleOCR repo from GitHub to use the fonts:

`!git clone https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR`

6. Run a codeblock to test that PaddleOCR is working. The codeblock is from the project description section on [PaddleOCR's pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/paddleocr/):

```
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR, draw_ocr
from PIL import Image
from IPython import display

img_path = '/content/test_img.PNG'
ocr = PaddleOCR(lang='en')
result = ocr.ocr(img_path,rec=False)
for idx in range(len(result)):
    res = result[idx]
    for line in res:
        print(line)

result = result[0]
image = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
im_show = draw_ocr(image, result, txts=None, scores=None, font_path='/content/PaddleOCR/StyleText/fonts/ko_standard.ttf')
im_show = Image.fromarray(im_show)
im_show.save('result.jpg')
display.Image('result.jpg')
```

The output is below:
[image: OCR_image]

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much. So, the error appears is because of the absence of libssl1.1 file?

Comment: That does seem to be the issue at this point

Comment: Okay understood. Appreciate your kind assistance. Thanks!